# How to keep the text formatting on pasting in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste

I'd like to edit the text before it is pasted.

My current code is:

```
element.on('paste', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var clipboardData = (event.originalEvent || event).clipboardData;
    var text = clipboardData.getData('text/html') || clipboardData.getData('text/plain') ||
    //document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, text);  <--     
});
```

I used this first but it sometimes fails and malforms the text formatting 
which I want to keep.

I think that using another function than execCommand will fix this bug, because I read more people are having trouble with this function and it has very limited support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element.on('paste', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var clipboardData = (event.originalEvent || event).clipboardData;
  var text = clipboardData.getData('text/html') || clipboardData.getData('text/plain') ||
  document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<pre>' + text + '</pre>');
});
```

Comment: I will test this and let you know how well it works. Could you please explain why surrounding my text by <pre> tags fix the bug? (it rarely occurs)

Comment: @Thomas It keeps the text formatted. I think that's exactly what you need.